# Volley me da el siguiente error JsonObjectResquest

Tags: android, json, api, volley

Estoy trabajando con Volley pero me da error al usarlo en el metodo. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Gracias:

```
public void sendResponse(){
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest jsObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    System.out.print(response.getString("amiiboSeries"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Error Respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage());

                    }
                });
            requestQueue.add(jsObjectRequest);
    }
```

Me da el error:

> Cannot resolve constructor 'JsonObjectResquest(int, (java.lang.String,
>   null, anonymus
>   com.Android.volley.Response.Listener, Anonymus
>   com.Android.Volley.Response.ErrorListener)'

Comment: Que version estas utilizando?

Comment: Paco, supongo que tienes una versión actualizada de Volley en tu proyecto. Entonces, debes cambiar el parámetro que ahora tienes como `null` por una cadena vacía. Yo así lo uso y me funciona: **`JsonObjectRequest jsObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, "", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {`**

Comment: Ahora sí. Gracias :D

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando la versión de [Volley mcxiaoke](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) la cual es obsoleta, y no contiene la clase `JsonObjectResquest`.

Debes usar la [versión más actual de Android Volley](https://github.com/google/volley/releases) y configurala en tu archivo `build.gradle`, por ejemplo:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    ...
}
```