# Obtener datos en respuesta json usando Volley

Tags: android, json, api, volley

Tengo este método que conecta con una API, básicamente me debería mostrar un resultado en un textView, pero no muestra nada y no sé porqué. Gracias.

```
   public void sendResponse(){
            String url = "http://www.amiiboapi.com/api/amiibo/";
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            JsonObjectRequest jsObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        miTextView.setText(response.getString("character"));


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Error Respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage());

                        }
                    });
            requestQueue.add(jsObjectRequest);
        }

Después de todo esto, no me vuelve a mostrar nada en el text view:
JsonObjectRequest jsObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsArray = response.getJSONArray("amiibo");
                    for(int i = 0;i < jsArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject object = jsArray.getJSONObject(i);                      
                        miTextView.setText(object.toString());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Error Respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage());

                    }
                });
        requestQueue.add(jsObjectRequest);
    }
```

Comment: No te muestra nada en el log cat? He visto 2 veces ese caso hoy. Estraño...

Comment: Paco ya planteaste esta pregunta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/131650/29967), tienes una respuesta y algunos comentarios, ¿por qué no haces caso a lo que se te dice ahllí y vuelves a plantear la misma pregunta?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Volley me da el siguiente error JsonObjectResquest](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131650/volley-me-da-el-siguiente-error-jsonobjectresquest). La pregunta ya fue planteada y se han sugerido soluciones que el OP no ha dado señales de haber probado. **Solución 1:** Cambiar el `null` por una cadena vacía `""`; **Solución 2:** Actualizar la librería de Volley, si está usando la versión obsoleta.

Comment: No es la misma pregunta. lo que me pasa aquí es que no me muestra nada en el textview. He hecho todo eso que se me ha dicho, si no lo hubiese hecho no habría llegado a este punto.

Comment: Bien, entonces debiste haber dicho que el problema es que no te imprime nada en el `TextView`... ¿Puedes imprimir `response` por ejemplo en el log y verificar que tiene realmente una llave llamada `character`?

Comment: He mirado en la api y sí la tiene, aquí está la api http://www.amiiboapi.com/api/amiibo/
También he probado con otras y no sale nada.

Comment: Ya, pero dentro de Android, después de: `public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {` puedes imprimir `response` para verificar que está llegando efectivamente la respuesta.

Comment: Si actualizaste la librería de Volley, **te falta cambiar el `null` por una cadena vacía**, así: **`JsonObjectRequest jsObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, "", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {`**, puede que no estés recibiendo nada a causa de eso.

Comment: Si lo cambio por una cadena vacía me da error.  Perdona estaba mirando una cosa.

Comment: Ah, el log me da un error de JSONException donde dice No value for character

Comment: ¿Tienes la librería Volley oficial de Android actualizada, o tienes aquella de Github, que es obsoleta?

Comment: Pues simplemente me dijeron que pusiese en el gradle esto: 'compile com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

Comment: Correcto, y si tenías la otra librería, supongo que la habrás quitado. Otra cosa por la que puede no estar funcionando es que deberás recorrer en un bucle tu respuesta, pues por el enlace se ve que hay varios objetos JSON.

Comment: La quité, si no me daba otro tipo de error al tener las dos ¿Simplemente con escribir eso en el gradle es suficiente?. Por cierto me ha dado un error de tipo RuntimeException donde dice Bad URL.

Comment: Vale, después de hacer el bucle me los acaba de mostrar. Ahora solo me falta parsearlos con GSON y crear un objeto de clase a partir de cada jsonobject. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la API responde el JSON completo que aparece en el enlace, entonces tienes que modificar la lectura del JSON.

La URL muestra un JSON así:

```
{
  "amiibo": [
    {
      "amiiboSeries": "Super Smash Bros.", 
      "character": "Mario", 
      "gameSeries": "Super Mario", 
      "head": "00000000", 
      "image": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/N3evin/AmiiboAPI/master/images/icon_00000000-00000002.png", 
      "name": "Mario", 
      "release": {
        "au": "2014-11-29", 
        "eu": "2014-11-28", 
        "jp": "2014-12-06", 
        "na": "2014-11-21"
      }, 
      "tail": "00000002", 
      "type": "Figure"
    }
....
```

Significa que el JSON está compuesto de una clave llamada `amiboo`, seguida de un Array, y dentro de ese array están los elementos por separado. En esa estructura, para llegar a `character`, tendrías entonces que hacer algo así:

```
JSONArray amiibo=response.getJSONArray("amiibo");
//Si quieres el primero: "Mario"
JSONObject firstJSON=amiibo[0]; //En amiibo hay varios elementos
String strCharacter=firstJSON.getString("character");  
miTextView.setText(strCharacter);
```

Al querer ponerlo en un `TextView`, se supone que tú estás buscando un solo elemento, entonces la API debería tener alguna petición que te permita filtrar los resultados.

Según sea el JSON, tendrás entonces que buscar los datos en él.

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta no tiene en la raiz un valor de `character`, se encuentra dentro del objeto de un array llamado `amiibo`

```
{  
   "amiibo":[  
      {  
         "amiiboSeries":"Super Smash Bros.",
         "character":"Mario",
         "gameSeries":"Super Mario",
         "head":"00000000",
```

Recuerda:

a respuesta y dependiendo de eso recuerda que la respuesta .Json puede ser de dos tipos:

> **- Si el .json inicia con `{` se considera como objeto Json.**
>
> **- Si el .json inicia con `[` es considerado como Arreglo Json.**

Por lo tanto, debes obtener el `JSONArray` y posteriormente buscar dentro del `JSONObject` el elemento `character` :

```
public void sendResponse(){
        String url = "http://www.amiiboapi.com/api/amiibo/";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest jsObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("amiibo");
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0); //0 indica el primer objeto dentro del array.
                    miTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("character")); //Agrega valor de character a TextView.


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Error Respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage());

                    }
                });
        requestQueue.add(jsObjectRequest);
    }
```